# Transfer operation using ConseilJS

Tags: transactions, javascript, conseil

I'm trying to use ConseilJS to make a transfer to a contract from a webpage.

I'm using  a `keystore` object  based on my `tezos-client`  wallet.

```
 const keystore = {
            publicKey: 'edpkvAsDWNg3ygZ11NDjsMFDgdQ3z9mmGAzfnYrc4Ch8NNTezyWy8o',
            privateKey: 'edsk4KYzU19Hj7wuZX9it5L6pyRwz9zss2wk627kkvuGJB7vXHcwB8',
            publicKeyHash: 'tz1bwT9XB9tpzTKKw7UtTSzS9dfXjAzqXzoi',
            seed: '',
            storeType: conseiljs.StoreType.Mnemonic
        };
```

I get the following JS error:

```
TypeError: invalid privateKey length
```

Indeed, my private key on `zeronet` doesn't have the same length as the one provided on the ConseilJS [tutorial](https://cryptonomic.github.io/ConseilJS/#/?id=transfer-value).

I get the same  error if I try to reconstruct a keystore using
`restoreIdentityWithSecretyKey`.

```
 const keystore = await conseiljs.TezosWalletUtil.restoreIdentityWithSecretKey('edsk4KYzU19Hj7wuZX9it5L6pyRwz9zss2wk627kkvuGJB7vXHcwB8')
```

Answer (score 1):

Please retry creating the keys from the faucet mnemonic, it sounds like you missed a few characters when copying the secret key.